# How can I make actual, working internal links in a Word 2019 document?

Tags: microsoft-word-2019

I am working on a book in Word 2019 and would ideally like to have the docx to be fit both for making PDFs for KDP print books, and for making Kindle books. I am willing to save to HTML and patch the HTML if I have to, but I would like my own table of contents to link chapter titles to the opening text for the chapter.

I followed [Add hyperlinks to a location within the same document](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-hyperlinks-to-a-location-within-the-same-document-1f24fc4f-7ccd-4c5f-87e1-9ddefb672e0e) and thought I had registered internal links successfully, by selecting the text I wanted to be a link, right-clicking on it, specifying an internal link, and then selecting a header. I did this with apparent success.

Then later, I went to try the links, and found them all irrelevant external links to locations posited to exist in the containing folder. The docx I am editing is itself at path `C:\Users\<username>\Documents\<title>.docx`, the link for the introduction works in that a control-click on it takes the user to the heading "Introduction", but none of the links to a heading containing a space work.

What happens when I click on the table of contents entry for "The Big Picture" is that on hover it displays a URL of `file:///c:\users\<username>\documents\the`, and control-clicking it gets a modal dialog saying "Cannot get the specified file."

The documentation page I linked to says that right-clicking on a selection should provide an option to put a "bookmark" at that text, but when I select part of the heading and right-click, I do not see a bookmark. (The page does refer to an older version of Word.)

How can I make actual, working internal links?

Comment: How have you managed to create bookmarks with blanks in them? My Word 365 won't let do that.

Comment: By following my nose. Word 2019 let me appear to do that, with apparent success on headings containing a space.

Comment: "Apparent" is perhaps the right word, but "bug" may be another (fixed in Word 365).

Comment: It may be a defect fixed that it shows apparent success instead of clearly disallowing it, but I would like some good and working way to link to headings containing a space.

Comment: The name of the bookmark does not need to be the same as the heading. You could replace the blank by underscore, for example.

Comment: How do I add a bookmark in Word 2019? I do not see the option listed in the menu that pops up when I right click.

Comment: Insert pane, Links drop-down list.

Comment: @harrymc It's working now; I converted headings to regular text, restored the previous styling, and gave bookmark names consisting only of letters and underscores. If you restate your comments as an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: Done as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Word, the format of a bookmark name is :

- may be between 1 and 40 characters long
- may consist of a combination of letters, digits and underscores
- may not start with a digit
- may not contain any kind of white space or punctuation.

The problem of the poster was that somehow Word let him define
bookmark names with blanks, on top of text containing blanks.
They then became unusable for linking.
This is probably a bug which I tested, and is already fixed in
Word 365.

Creating bookmarks is done in the Insert pane, Links drop-down list.